# Checking the c:if condition in jsp with request.getAttribute in different jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, attributes, jstl

I am trying to set the attribute value in head.jsp using

```
 request.setAttribute("pageLib", pageLib);
```

Now, while i try to check the condition in body.jsp using

```
   <c:if test="${request.getAttribute('pageLib')}">
         <script src="" type="module" ></script>
   </c:if>
```

This is giving an error of "**The function getAttribute must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified**"

But when printing the value gives the right boolean value.

```
<% out.println("User Name is " +request.getAttribute("pageLib")); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
  ${request.getAttribute('pageLib')}
```

use

```
  ${pageLib}
```